# Создание Task для ExecutorService которая будет void?

Tags: java, многопоточность, execute

Есть пул потоков:

```
private final ExecutorService service = ...;
```

Я добавляю туда задачи:

```
Future<Boolean> collectTXTFiles = service.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {...});
```

Но среди этих задач есть и такая которая `void`, и возвращать там в принципе нечего, делать затычку-костыль возвращая какую-нибудь ерунду, мне не хочется. Зачем код портить...

Но и отказываться от идеи использовать здесь `ExecutorService`, я не хочу. `Future` принимает только `Callable<T>` объекты, а без `<T> call()` ни как. Подскажите что тут можно сделать?

Возможно ли задать `void` задачу для `ExecutorService`?

Comment: Можно вместо `Boolean` использовать `Void`, но там всё равно придётся возвращать результат (`null`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибаетесь. В ExecutorService можно передавать в методе submit интерфейс Runnable